# Simulation for repeatedly taking gloves until a matching pair is found

Tags: java, linked-list

I created the following code that simulates a person taking a random glove from a drawer until he/she gets a matching pair of gloves:

```
LinkedList<String> glovesList = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> matchList = new LinkedList<String>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] glovesAvailable = {"red left", "red left", "red left", "red left", "red left",
                                    "red right", "red right", "red right", "red right", "red right",
                                    "yellow left", "yellow left", "yellow left", "yellow left",
                                    "yellow right", "yellow right", "yellow right", "yellow right",
                                    "green left", "green left", "green right", "green right"};

        // adding the gloves inside the list
        for(int i = 0; i < glovesAvailable.length; i++) {
            glovesList.add(glovesAvailable[i]);
        }


        // taking out the gloves from the drawer
        while(glovesList.size() != 0) {
            int n = rand.nextInt(glovesList.size());
            System.out.println("Removed a " + glovesList.get(n));
            matchList.add(glovesList.remove(n));
            if((matchList.contains("red left") && matchList.contains("red right")) ||
               (matchList.contains("yellow left") && matchList.contains("yellow right")) ||
               (matchList.contains("green left") && matchList.contains("green right"))) {
                System.out.println("Pair found!");
                break;
            }
        }

        // rechecking list if there are no more items
        System.out.println("Iterations till a matching pair is found: " + matchList.size());
        System.out.println("List of gloves taken out: " + matchList);
        System.out.println("Remaining gloves: " + glovesList.size());
```

The code works, but I am interested in making it more efficient. How can this code be improved?

Comment: for starters, why do you need an array if all it does is fill the list?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052959/data-structure-that-allows-accessing-elements-by-index-and-delete-them-in-o1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current implementation has some very inefficient points:

- Accessing elements in a `LinkedList` by index is inefficient, because it requires iterating until the correct element. This effects the step of getting a random item from `glovesList`, and also the step of removing that item.
- `matchList.contains` is inefficient, because it requires scanning the list for the item. And there are multiple calls to `matchList.contains` per glove pulled, making the problem even worse.

A few simple tricks could make a big improvement:

- Do not create a `LinkedList` from the `String[] glovesAvailable`. And instead of a `String[]`, create it as a `List<String>`, so that you can easily shuffle it with `Collections.shuffle`. Once shuffled, simply pick gloves from it from the beginning, no need to remove elements.
- Instead of a `LinkedList` for `matchList`, use a `Set<String> picked`.
- Create a `Map<String, String> pairs` to efficiently find a pair in `picked` as you iterate over `gloves`.

Something like this:

```
Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<>();
pairs.put("red right", "red left");
pairs.put("red left", "red right");
pairs.put("green right", "green left");
pairs.put("green left", "green right");
pairs.put("yellow right", "yellow left");
pairs.put("yellow left", "yellow right");

List<String> gloves = Arrays.asList("red left", "red left", "red left", "red left", "red left",
    "red right", "red right", "red right", "red right", "red right",
    "yellow left", "yellow left", "yellow left", "yellow left",
    "yellow right", "yellow right", "yellow right", "yellow right",
    "green left", "green left", "green right", "green right");

Collections.shuffle(gloves);

Set<String> picked = new HashSet<>();

for (String glove : gloves) {
  System.out.println("Picked a " + glove);
  if (picked.contains(pairs.get(glove))) {
    System.out.println("Pair found!");
    return;
  }
  picked.add(glove);
}
```

As the other answer pointed out,
there is indeed a risk of spelling errors
(and also when creating the `pairs` map).
It would be better to replace the glove strings with constants or enums.

Answer (score 1):

Make the glove types an enum

```
public static enum GLOVE {
  RED_LEFT, RED_RIGHT,
  YELLOW_LEFT, YELLOW_RIGHT, 
  GREEN_LEFT, GREEN_RIGHT
}
```

this has several benefits:

1. with the current String solution, you can have a typo and you will not detect this until run time.  With an enum, the compiler checks values for you
2. the `matchList.contains...` if statement can be replaced by iteration on enum values
3. checking equality on enum values is faster then String comparison

if you want an even better solution, you should make a `Glove` class with two attributes, `color` of type enum and `hand` of type enum.  then, implement `equals()` and `hash()` methods so you can put `Glove` instances in various `Collection`s. The benefit if this solution is that it allows for future modification to Glove specifications (like, adding colors, adding `material` attribute, etc)